# Design of Comment-Feature for multiple database objects

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jakarta-ee, ejb

In my application I have multiple objects that I would like to add comments to. Every one of these objects is represented in its own database table. Beside being connected to a specific object, all comments share a common context in which the corresponding objects exist. What I tried for now is to use JPA-inheritance with `InheritanceType.SingleTable` so I can store the foreign keys to every 'commentable'-object in one table and the discriminator-feature to seperate that table into different Comment-Subclasses in JPA:

**Superclass Comment.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMENT_TABLE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "COMMENT_OBJECT_TYPE")
public class Comment {
    protected String text;

    protected CommonContext context;
    ...
}
```

**Subclass Object A**

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "OBJECT A")
public class ObjectAComment extends Comment {

    private ObjectA objectA;

    // OneToMany-Relation exists in Object A accordingly
    @JoinColumn(name = "FK_OBJECT_A")
    @ManyToOne
    public ObjectA getObjectA() { return objectA; }

    public void setObjectA(ObjectA objectA) { this.objectA = objectA; }
}
```

The other comment-classes for the other objects are designed just as for object A. The common context shall be used to get all comments for a specific situation and I would like to have a comment know its owner, so that I can easily link to that object in my application. Without the latter I had to go through all objects of that type to search for any that has comments, as not every object has them.

On designing the REST-endpoints and the EJBs I ended up creating specific methods for every subclass of `Comment.java`. For example for creating a comment I have

```
@POST
@Path("comments/objectA")
public Response createCommentForObjectA(ObjectAComment comment) { ... }

@POST
@Path("comments/objectB")
public Response createCommentForObjectB(ObjectBComment comment) { ... }

...
```

This feels a bit cumbersome as I would rather have

```
@POST
@Path("comments")
public Response createComment(Comment comment) { ... }
```

which is impossible with the current design as I would lose the specific information for the different objects. Now I see three possible ways to go on:

## Version 1

I stick with the current solution and create CRUD-methods for every type of comment.

## Version 2

A friend suggested, that I could use transient properties in `Comment.java`:

```
public class Comment {
    ...
    private COMMENT_OBJECT_TYPE objectType;
    private long idObject;

    @Transient
    public long getIdObject() { return idObject; }
    ...

    @Transient
    public COMMENT_OBJECT_TYPE getObjectType() { return objectType; }
    ...
}
```

With this I could generalize the parameter of the REST-endpoint and return specific objects depending on the object type:

```
@POST
@Path("comments")
public Response createComment(Comment comment) {
    // return ObjectAComment, ObjectBComment, ... depending on the object type
}
```

## Version 3

Ditch the whole `@Inheritance` and `@DiscriminatorColumn`, put everything in one JPA-class and do the whole organizing of the comment context myself. Additionaly I would lose type safety.

None of these solutions feels completely right to me, hence I would like to ask if there is a preferable way to design this kind of comment feature and is there maybe something I am missing completely?

## Edit 1

Added information that all comments and objects share a common context. Renamed previous `COMMENT_CONTEXT` to `COMMENT_OBJECT_TYPE` to avoid a misunderstanding between this common context and the object type a comment is related to.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use inheritance for different Comments? Couldn't you instead use a single Comment class and composition to embed it into commentable entities?

Comment: No there is none other than maybe type safety which might be negligible in this scenario. The commentable entities already have a link to a list of related comments, but I also want to have a link from a comment to its owner.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like your Comment is a standalone entity without dependencies on other entities. A comment has an owner, but should not know who is owning it. So I would add a column on the comment table "ownerUuid". The entire comments "bounded context" knows nothing about the other entities.

When creating a comment you always provide the ownerUuid. Same for retrieval. So you can create comments for any entity having a uuid.

However this means you need to add UUID columns in your already existing tables.

This to me seems like the cleanest solution. This way your comment system can stand on it's own without heavy impact on other entities.

---

EDIT

Because of the extra information. I would suggest following approach.
Keep in mind that I do not know how the owner of the Comment is used, so the suggestion might not be perfect for this scenario.

As the comment should know the owner object I would suggest doing the following:
Have an interface `CommentOwner` with methods:

- `getUuid()`
- `getContext()`
- `Any other information you might need from the owner`

A `Comment` will have a `CommentOwner` property.
Every entity that you want to contain Comments, should implement this interface. When creating a Comment you provide the CommentOwner.
This way you can retrieve comments Based on Context. A Comments has a direct link to its owner, but still does not need to know about the specific classes of the owners.

Comment: Thats an interesting soltuion as well, but I would like a comment to know which its owner is, either by using the object relation and foreign key in the subclasses (Version 1 and 2) or with everything in the superclass (Version 3). I want to easily create queries like "get all comments on objects of type A" which seems a bit harder with your approach or am I mistaken?

Comment: That is indeed harder to do. You would need to add something like "ownerType" to the comment. That way you could still do the query based on type. But may I ask why you would need such a query. I can't seem to think of a scenario where you would want all comments of a certain objectType.

Comment: All comments share a common context, in which also every objects exists. This context is managed by the super class `Comment.java`. Comments are created for an object, whenever something happens, that cannot be dealt with by the object itself. I would like to get all comments for said context, so that I don't have to go through all objects to see if there are any comments. Secondly I would like to have a comment know its owner, so that I can easily link to the specific object in my application. I updated the question, as this information seems more crucial than I first anticipated.

Comment: I updated my answer. Hopefully this is closer to the solution you are looking for

Comment: Could you post what approach you followed?

Comment: Oh sorry, I totally forgot. I posted my approach as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with version 3, keeping every information in one Comment-class.  The subclasses which I would've achieved with `@Inheritance` and `@DiscriminatorColumn` would only have one property, the foreign key to the commentable object, and wouldn't differ in what they represent in general and how they would be used.

My class looks something like this now:

```
public class Comment {
    private String text;

    private CommonContext context;

    private COMMENT_OBJECT_TYPE objectType;

    private ObjectA objectA;
    private ObjectB objectB;
    ...

    @JoinColumn(name = FK_OBJECT_A)
    @ManyToOne
    public ObjectA getObjectA() { return objectA; }

    public void setObjectA(ObjectA objectA) { this.objectA = objectA; }

    ...
}
```